# Finding lost coax

Tags: coaxial-cable

I've made an error while pulling some coax up in the attic of my house. I pulled too far and pulled the end which should connect to the back of the face plate up into the wall, and it's stuck somewhere now. To make matters worse, it's an exterior wall, on a two story home.

I went into my drywall downstairs to try to find the stuck end. It's not there. I ran fish tape (aka jet line) down the hole where the coax comes up into the attic but can't find the end of the fish tape from the downstairs side.

I also tried to feed the fish tape up to the attic from downstairs, both on the inside through the drywall and also up the outside where the air conditioner lines run up to the attic, but again no luck

Does any audible tester exist for coax to trace a disconnected coax cable from the outside of a wall, similar to what exists for electrical wire tracing? If not, what are my options to get this fixed and run back down again? I was trying to replace an RG59 run with RG6, and it was going great until I realized I pulled too far...

Pictures uploaded: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1wrACptj6QeCtrI7wXYzb024uqLlTMwOm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one of these [Tone Generator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00279JLBQ) and it does coax.

Generally you need two fish tapes to hook onto each other which is typically achieved by pushing both into the cavity and then rotating one so that it hooks the other.  I don't typically have much luck with that approach - probably requires more technique than I have.

When I run wire like this I use plumbers chain and feed that down through a hole, if there is no insulation then it will fall by gravity and weight in a straight line.  The chain also allows you to tie and twist a wire to use as a pull.

I don't know where your start point and finish point are for this wire.  Assuming this wire is coming from the service provider access box on the outside and going to a room inside somewhere pretty much all installers would just surface mount on the outside of the house from the access point to as close to the final location as possible and drill through there.  Fishing wire is a pain and time consuming.  Kind of ugly to have surface mounted wires on the outside of your house but really depends on how perfect your exterior is to start with.

Comment: Will this tester work from outside of the wall? I had seen this one but it looked it it needed to touch the core wire of the cable. I was thinking of using my extension ladder and checking along the siding if this will do it though. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works though 1/2" drywall when I've toned 14/2 wire.  I haven't tried on coax in a wall but I expect it would work.

Comment: Just an update. It worked like a champ! I was worried it wouldn't be able to detect the signal through the coax shielding, but it did. I found the spot where it got stuck in the wall, and it wasn't nearly as far as I was worried it would be, so it was a simple fix once the end was located! Thank you again!